# How to set one column true which will make all other entity value false in sql?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a column in a user table as IsAdmin bit. There can be only one person admin at a time. Therefore, What I would like is to constraint the table to set all other users IsAdmin value to false on setting one user true? I can achieve this by going one by one to set all users false obviously but I just wonder whether there is already something out there handles these kinds of scenarios. I appreciate your help.

Comment: It's probably easier to just set all users to false first, but if you want to go the more complex path, you can probably handle this with a trigger. http://www.sqlteam.com/article/an-introduction-to-triggers-part-i

Comment: You can have a (pseudo-) constraint that enforces (at most one) user having `IsAdmin` set, but constraints don't make *changes* to data - not even in the row that is currently being considered, let alone other rows.

Comment: I was actually expecting a better way of doing this. it seems to set all values false first then set the one true is easiest way of doing this job?

Comment: Btw, I am using entity framework. so I can create a method to do this job I believe. I was wondering only if there was a better approach these types of problems.

Comment: What if just add another table `tblAdmins` with `user_id` field and one row so you only need to update this table to change Admin?

Comment: @valex yes I also thought about this but this diverts me on other issues. I only use one entity and I do not want to any join tables. I was thinking about this like a group of radio buttons where once you check one radio button it automatically unchecks the other radio buttons and only one radio button can be checked in the group.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `trigger` to solve this problem.
Write a `trigger` before updating a row, and the `trigger` is used to make all columns `false`, and after the trigger set one column to `true`

```
create trigger trigger-name on table-name
before update
as
begin
    update table-name set column-name=false;
end 
go
```

Comment: Triggers can be tricky to get right - you need to consider e.g. a multi-row insert or update that attempts to make *multiple* rows `IsAdmin` simultaneously.

Comment: So what is your suggestion @Damien_The_Unbeliever?

Comment: @akdurmus - I would probably implement a constraint to *enforce* that at most one column is marked as Admin, and provide a stored procedure for switching it. Having a well named stored proc (hopefully) makes it clear that only one user can by Admin, but the constraint ensures that any direct table updates/inserts don't violate the requirement.